# yadcf initial filter value when page loads

Tags: php, datatables, yadcf

So I have been looking around for an answer on how to do this and haven't had much luck so I thought I would post something on here.  What I'm looking for is a way to set a default value for a filter so when the page loads it will automatically search the datatable according to this initial value.  For example. I would like to pre-load the range_date filter with a specific date - A date that will actually be taken from a $_GET variable, so this value can not be hard coded. My current column code looks like this....

```
{column_number : 4, filter_type: "range_date", date_format: 'yy-mm-dd'},`enter code here`
```

So far I have found one source about adding `exFilterColumn` but there are no examples on how to get this working with `filter_type: "range_date"`  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of digging I have figured out how to get `exFilterColumn` working with a range_date filter.  First I had to add the following to my column initialization:

```
filter_delay: 1500, filter_default_label: 'Search'
```

Then I had to add

```
yadcf.exFilterColumn(tableOne, [
    [1, {
        from: '2016-11-02',
        to: '2016-11-03'
    }],
]);
```

My complete code looks like this:

```
// Appointment datatable
        var table = $('#tableID').dataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{
                url :"ajax/users-get-table-data.php" // json datasource
                type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                data:"workOrderStatusID=2",
            },
        }).yadcf([
            {column_number : 0, filter_type: "text", filter_default_label: ['Search']},
            {column_number : 1, filter_type: "range_date", date_format: 'yy-mm-dd', filter_delay: 1500, filter_default_label: 'Search'}
        ]);

        yadcf.exFilterColumn(table, [
            // 1 is the matching column of my targeted range_date filter
            [1, {
                <? //setting the date from get variable
                $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_GET['date']);
                $tomorrow = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date . "+1 days"));
                ?>
                from: '<? echo $date; ?>',
                to: '<? echo $tomorrow; ?>'
            }],
        ]);
```

Incase you are reading this and want to pre load a regular column filter (not a range date) you can use the following:

```
yadcf.exFilterColumn(table, [
    // 1 being the column number, and "value" being the value you want it to initially search for when page loads
    [1, "value"]
]);
```